# Dealing with Unicode Characters

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode, character-encoding

I know this question has been asked countless times before, but I can't seem to get any of the solutions working. I've tried using the `codecs` module, the `io` module. Nothing seems to work.

I'm scraping some stuff off the web, then logging the details of each item to a text file, yet the script breaks as soon as it first encounters a Unicode character.

`AHIMSA Centro de Sanación Pránica, Pranic Healing`

Further, I'm not sure where and or when Unicode characters might pop up, which adds an extra level of complexity, so I need an overarching solution and I'm not exactly sure how to deal with potential non-ASCII characters.

I'm not sure if I'll have Python 3.6.5 in the production environment, so the solution has to work with 2.7.

**What can I do here? How can I deal with this?**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
...
with open('test.txt', 'w') as f:
f.write(str(len(discoverable_cards)) + '\n\n')
    for cnt in range(0, len(discoverable_cards)):
        t = get_time()
        f.write('[ {} ] {}\n'.format(t, discoverable_cards[cnt]))
        f.write('[ {} ] {}\n'.format(t, cnt + 1))
        f.write('[ {} ] {}\n'.format(t, product_type[cnt].text))
        f.write('[ {} ] {}\n'.format(t, titles[cnt].text))
...
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: are you using python 2 or 3?

Comment: @MatthewStory python 2.7 i should've added that

Comment: If you open the file in `wb` rather than `w` mode, you can write to the file as a bytes string. `f.write(bytes('[ {} ] {}\n'.format(t, discoverable_cards[cnt])))`. That way, your encoding won't get angry

Comment: @C.Nivs funny, i was using `wb` before, then switched to `w` since you can't append as you normally would to `wb` files :/ how do u append to files created with `wb`?

Comment: @C.Nivs ***i'm still getting the error with `wb` :/***

Comment: Ah, forgot about that behavior

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you are in python2.7 you will probably want to explicitly encode all of your strings with a unicode compatible character set like "utf8" before passing them to `write`, you can do this with a simple encode method:

```
def safe_encode(str_or_unicode):
    # future py3 compatibility: define unicode, if needed:
    try:
       unicode
    except NameError:
       unicode = str
    if isinstance(str_or_unicode, unicode):
        return str_or_unicode.encode("utf8")
    return str_or_unicode
```

You would then use it like this:

```
f.write('[ {} ] {}\n'.format(safe_encode(t), safe_encode(discoverable_cards[cnt])))
```

Comment: why is there no dash in `return str_or_unicode.encode('utf8')`? why isnt `utf8` `utf-8`? maybe thats what i was doing wrong. you see both versions being used everywhere and i had just assumed that `utf8` was a typo

Comment: It should work either way. The most common reason that an encode fails is when you call it on an already encoded string. This is one of the worst design flaws in Python 2.7. When you call "encode" on a string, it first decodes to a unicode object using the `ASCII` charset, and then calls `encode` with your passed encoding. That's the reason why `safe_encode` checks to make sure it's a unicode object before encoding it. Python 3 solves this by only defining encode on unicode objects and decode on strings, so you get an AttributeError if you try to encode a string rather than a weird unicode bug

Comment: i think i know what youre talking about. when i was trying to encode b4 the strings before, it would throw an error if the code was a string. this is what youre talking about right?

Comment: Yup. Encoding an already "utf8" encoded string with "utf8" will throw an error in python 2 ... pretty rad.

Comment: NOTE the 'safe_encode' definition will *break* if this is ran on python3 (unicode isn't defined in py3 anymore). You can fix like this:

try:
  unicode
except NameError:
  unicode  = str

BTW, in general it is difficult to keep code compatible with py2 and py3 and also have it work correctly with unicode.

Comment: @LeoK much appreciated. maybe edit the answer? `try/except` wraps the `if` statement?